# How to bind Dropdown List in asp.net MVC from Database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner in MVC and trying to bind drop-down list to a model using data from a database lookup table.

My Model:

```
 public class State
{
    [Required]
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }

}
```

In my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddState()
{
    State obj = new State();
    using (MvcWorkEntities context = new MvcWorkEntities())
    {
        obj.CountryList = context.Mst_Country.ToList();
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

The View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddState","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Select Country")
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.CountryId,Model.CountryList);
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Enter State Name")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StateName)
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This isn't working as intended and I don't understand where I am going wrong. Could anyone point out where I might be making a mistake?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples of this kind of thing online already, you're not the first person to have such a requirement. Couldn't you find anything which helped?

Comment: Bro I tried but not get the desired answer,  there are many resources available online but as i am a beginner so i find difficult to understand them. Finally I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId , new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryId))
```

also you can use viewbag,viewdata and etc

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList, "Please select")
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your view file

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddState","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Select Country")
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.CountryId,new SelectList(Model.CountryId,"value","text");
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Link:https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdown-lists-in-razor-views-using-the-mvvm-design-pattern-entity-framework-and-ajax