# MVC 5 bootstrap dropdown with dynamic anchors

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

i want to add li elements to this bootstrap dropdown from database

```
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Apps<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">App 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">App 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">App 3</a></li>            
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The objective is to populate the anchor with a path for a different application so user can redirect to applications it has access to. Although, I'm not sure how can i populate this.

Note. It is possible to be more apps because Administrators will be able to add more apps for users to access in database

Comment: If there will be only 3 apps, you can simply pass the data using the viewbag and render it here. If it is dynamic then you can fill up the dropdown by selectlist passing in viewbag. You can use the dropdownlistfor and assign the class to use it as bootstrap.

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to mention that on backend admins can add more apps for user to access, hence why needs to be dynamic

Comment: You can bind the dropdown like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092128/how-to-bind-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-mvc-from-database-using-entity-framework

For bootstrap, probably you need to add a class so the result will be generated as above.

Comment: seems like the way to go, but yes my biggest issue was really how to render said dropdown with that layout on bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your application model is

```cs
public class App
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you passed application collection as `List<App>` you can do the following

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    @foreach (App app in Model.Applications)
    {
        <li><a href="@app.Url">@app.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, this is probably the simplest approach, I was thinking about using foreach for this but didn't know where to start!